# Solenoid fails under PWM control

Tags: mosfet, pwm, esp32, solenoid

I have a 12V solenoid rated at about ~6W and 40kg pull.
I am controlling it using ESP32, IRLB8721PBF logic-level mosfet.
MOSFET gate-gnd is also connected using 0.5W 5.6V zener diode.
ESP32-gate is also connected with a 10k resistor in series.
(I have tried removing it but it doesn't change anything)

While the solenoid is rated for 100% duty, I would like to reduce overheating using PWM.
At different frequencies, I am switching the MOSFET ON and OFF.

At about 1000Hz, it seems to work fine but the holding force is not great(1-2kg).
I tried going into 10000Hz, but it creates a very weird effect where it stays powered for 12 seconds and then it stays OFF for another 12 seconds.

What went wrong here?
What frequency would be useful to reduce overheating and keep the holding force close to original?
Do I need different parts to efficiently perform PWM at high frequency?

*I apologise for my lack of schema drawing skills, I have described the board instead*

Comment: Look up what a gate driver is. 10K is way too high for a gate resistor, by the way. Remember, the gate-source is a capacitance and along with a gate resistor makes an RC. and when you're trying to switch a MOSFET real fast, that matters.

Comment: I am aware of gate drivers, however I am trying to understand the missing piece and add it without adding a whole gate driver

Comment: Agreed that the gate resistance is too high. I'm assuming that your zener is your flywheel for your motor? Apologies, I'm trying to visualize your setup in my head 

Comment: yes, it aims to protect ESP32 from EMF kickback from the solenoid

Comment: is incorrect resistor the only problem if behaviour stays the same with no resistor at all?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you have latchup somewhere.

You probably need a gate driver at 10 kHz.

The gate resistor is also far too high. It forms an RC with the gate-source capacitance and that matters when you are trying to switch the MOSFET very fast. Gate resistors are normally under 10 Ohms. They are meant to suppress things like ringing.

Another issue is the flyback diode. It's not in a good place. Connecting it across the gate-source doesn't do nothing but only because it is a zener diode. Flyback voltage spikes easily destroy the source-drain of a MOSFET which has a far higher rating than the gate-source MOSFET. If you suppress that then the issue never gets to the gate to begin with.

So placing a zener anti-parallel with the drain-source is better, but still not the best because it requires the freewheeling solenoid current travels through the power source.

The best thing to do in your case is to place a fast diode anti-parallel with the solenoid. This provides a tight, low impedance loop for the solenoid current to circulate which supresses the flyback voltage at its source. A diode in this position is suppressing the flyback voltage by allowing the solenoid flyback current to flow in forward conduction. Therefore this does not need to be a zener diode since it is not doing its job by breaking down in reverse and clamping the voltage. The diode should be a fast-type, however.

**NOTE:** In things like an H-bridge, you cannot place a flyback diode in parallel with the motor or inductive load since current can drive through the motor in both directions. Doing so would result in a short-circuit.

The diodes anti-parallel with each MOSFET drain-source in an H-bridge, in pairs, provide a circulating flyback current path around the motor exactly like the anti-parallel diode to the solenoid in your circuit. These are equivalent.

Too many beginners working with low-side switching circuits like yours look at the flyback diode anti-parallel to the MOSFETs in an H-bridge and then transfer them their circuit thinking they are the same thing. **They are not.** In your type of circuit, a non-zener diode anti-parallel to the MOSFET source-drain will not protect against flyback voltage spike because the current paths are all wrong. It would only provide some protection if it were a zener diode, and as mentioned earlier, it is still not very good.

Comment: so I add a Schottky diode as close to solenoid, as possible. then there is no need for additional protection of mosfet or esp32, is that correct? should I aim for 100V, 200V Schottky or which one exactly(what's the possible kickback voltage from this solenoid)?

Comment: @underflow  Correct. It will clamp the solenoid flyback voltage spike to the forward voltage drop of the Schottky. The diode used needs to have a reverse voltage that can tolerate the power supply, since that is what it will be blocking most of the time. There is no limit to kickback spike from a solenoid. The current going through an inductance *will* continue to flow after you try to interrupt current through it, and if the lowest impedance path available is extremely high then so too will the voltage be required to keep that current going.

Comment: @underflow You might want to read about exactly what inductive flyback is. It sounds like you don't entirely know. Imagine trying to stop a moving train coasting down the tracks. That's current. What force will the train hit something with? That depends on how hard you try to stop it. Flyback voltage is the same. If you reroute the train onto a circular loop and give it time to easily coast to a stop then then the force required is very low. That's what the diode literally does. If you place a brick wall in front of it, it will hit hard. If you use a steel the train will hit very, very hard.

Comment: "there is no limit to kickback spike from a solenoid" I thought there was a formula so we could at least estimate? how I can make sure that the chosen diode is enough and not an overkill as well?

Comment: @underflow Whatever equation you are talking about would only be limited by the materials present until the flyback voltage blasts a path. And I do not think you understood my explanation of kickback when you are still asking about how to size the diode for the voltage spike. You don't size for the voltage spike because if that spike is actually reached, then you did not do anything about it and components are already damaged. It would be like designing airbags to hit your face with the same force your face slams against the steering wheel without airbags. You want it to never reach that point

Comment: Therefore, with your zener, you would size to the voltage required to not fry the components.  With the Schottky it clamps to the forward voltage drop which won't kill any MOSFET so you don't worry about that. Instead you would size the voltage so the power supply doesn't fry it when it's just sitting there. And in all cases you would size it to handle the flyback CURRENT circulating through it. What you're trying to do is provide an easy CURRENT path so that voltage does not need to be so high that components are damaged. You don't need to know what that voltage spike actually goes to.

Answer (score 0):

lower the resistor between the ESP33 output and the gate. I would use 100 Ohm. At the moment you are wasting a lot of power when switching on and off the MOSFET.

You may go down to 10 Ohm.

Select a frequency, let's say 1 kHz, and then modulate the duty cycle.

Keep in mind the following thing:

If the relay requires a certain number of milliamps to have a pulling force of 40 kg, the MOSFET must sink that current, no matter how you modulate the current.

Comment: would it behave differently with 10Ohm than with no resistor at all? because removing the resistor did not result in any improvement

Comment: you're also saying that there would be no power saving as MOSFET will burn the additional current. I am pretty sure I saw some designs where people saved battery using PWM control, is that not possible here?

Comment: I think the point is that solenoids require less voltage to hold the object than to pull it, so with PWM control we are not really aiming for "40kg pull force" per se and there will be energy savings. I only need to pull the object once and then hold it, maybe that wasn't clear